# Powershell back up script

Tags: windows, powershell, scripting, robocopy

So a couple of years ago I created a script that could be used and executed Windows PC that would make a backup / copy of all PDFs in a user's document folder to a flash drive regardless of username. The script also does not use the drive letter to identify the flash drive, instead, it uses the drives Volume name. So that no matter where it was used, which pc, user or letter of the flash drive, it always worked.

However now I just recreated it and for some reason, the script runs without a hitch, it is not copying the pdfs to the flash drive any longer. Any help figuring out why would be nice. I am not a pro at Powershell.

```
param([parameter(mandatory=$true)]$VolumeName) $backupPath = $null 
get-wmiobject win32_logicaldisk | % { if ($_.VolumeName -eq $VolumeName) {  $backupDrive = $_.DeviceID } } 
$backupPath = $backupDrive + "\"
robocopy $env:username\Documents\ *.pdf $backupDrive /MIR /Z /XJD
Remove-ItemProperty -Path 'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\RunMRU' -Name '*' -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
Remove-Item -path $env:username\Downloads\backup.ps1 -recurse
```

Answer (score 0):

You create the variable `$backupPath` but you use the variable `backupDrive` in your robocopy commandline. Instead of `$env:UserPorfile` you use `$env:userName`. I doubt that this script run sucessfully once. And you have some unrelated code lines in it.

```
param(
    [parameter(mandatory = $true)]
    $VolumeName
) 
$backupDrive = (Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_LogicalDisk | Where-Object -Property VolumeName -EQ -Value $VolumeName).DeviceID
$backupPath = $backupDrive + '\'
robocopy $Env:USERPROFILE\Documents\ $backupPath *.pdf /S /Z /XJD /NDL /PURGE
```

You might have asked the author where you downloaded this script to fix it. ;-)

Comment: haha, this isn't my own script not completely. I took some lines from stuff I found in forums and edited them to fit my purpose. However, there are ALOT of lines that are my own. However I am extremely green to coding and scripting, it probably took me a week to come up with this script. That was 2 years ago and I have not touched it since, It use to work perfectly which is why i'm confused as to why it runs now but doesn't copy the files. Thanks for your suggestions tho. I will take a look at it and see if that fixes the issues.    P..S. don't be so quick to assume. ;-)

Comment: Concerning the use of $backupPath vs $backupDrive. I believe you skipped over this part of the script which sets one to the other. $backupPath = $backupDrive + "\"

Comment: Did you try my code suggestion? Did it work?  ... and this `$backupPath = $backupDrive + "\"` is from your code ...

Comment: Yes I did, here is the code where I made the changes. Let me try the code you wrote as well :)

Comment: param([parameter(mandatory=$true)]$VolumeName) $backupPath = $null
get-wmiobject win32_logicaldisk | % { if ($_.VolumeName -eq $VolumeName) {  $backupPath = $_.DeviceID } }
$backupPath = $backupDrive + "\"
robocopy $env:userProfile\Documents\ *.pdf $backupDrive /MIR /Z /XJD

Comment: I just ran the script with your revisions and I am still encountering the same issue. The script runs well, no files copied though. Same as with my script. I am at my witts end. lol

Comment: Changed the code. Try it now. I just ran it and it works for me.

Comment: It runs fine, shows 4 files, which is right but also shows 0 were copied and 4 was skipped.  [link](https://ibb.co/mhRxtVf)

Comment: [powershell output](https://ibb.co/mhRxtVf)                                    https://ibb.co/mhRxtVf

Comment: The picture shows 4 of 4 directories have been skipped and 0 of 0 files have been copied. So obviously the script works as expected. The robocopy command runs just fine. It's not the fault of the script if there are no files to copy.

Comment: ...Then what could it be? Cause everything else seems to be in place. I even went back through the script line for line to relearn it and how it works just to make sure I wasn't being trolled here. haha 


My other question is why in line 6 did you set $backupPath = $backupDrive + '\' ..if
in line 7 you use $backupPath. When it seems that $backupDrive should be used instead? or am I missing something completely.

Comment: You already asked this and I was unsure what you mean. I create a variable containing the drive letter with a trailing backslash as destination for robocopy. What happens when you run the robocopy command by hand? It looks like you don't have *pdf files in your Documents folder. I just tested the robocopy command and it works for me.

Comment: yes, I know I already asked, because I'm still having the same issue. The first time I asked I thought maybe it was something in my script or maybe something changed in Powershell.  I understand how your script works and what you did. I am asking the 2nd time becasue if the problems is not with the scripts, then what other issue could cause the files not to be copied. I can assure you have many PDF files in my documents folder. I am learning, not slow. reassuring I had PDFs in my docs folder was the very first thing I checked and made sure of,

Comment: What can I say? The screenshot of the robocopy output says something else. I cannot troubleshoot your computer. Sorry.

Comment: I figured out the issue on my side, and it is A REALLY dumb on to have. Even though OneDrive is completely uninstalled from my system, for some reason, it is still showing up as part of the file system/directory path. So after changing the path to $Env:USERPROFILE\OneDrive\Documents\ it works like it should. Your version as well my orginal. ......so yeah..completely dumb on win10 and partly myside as well..... Thanks for your help.